# D3v4 distintos símbolos para las posiciones de los datos

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-v4.js

Estoy intentando hacer que en mi gráfico `d3`, dependiendo de la posición del array en la que se encuentra el dato, se pinte un símbolo u otro.

Estoy haciendo varias pruebas y me funciona relativamente bien, cuando selecciono un `checkbox` me pone el símbolo correcto, y si selecciono el otro, más de lo mismo, es decir, funciona bien cuando solo selecciono un `checkbox`. El problema viene cuando selecciono los dos, este me pone el simbolo del segundo `checkbox`.

Código *HTML*:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="planned_checked"  id="eae" > eaepunt1
    <input type="checkbox" name="planned_checked"  id="arab" > arabpunt1
</br>
<select name="type" id="type" onchange="mostrarDatos()" >
    <option value="1">Circle</option>
    <option value="2">Cross</option>
    <option value="3">Diamond</option>
    <option value="4">Square</option>
    <option value="5">Star</option>
    <option value="6">Triangle</option>
    <option value="7">Wye</option>
</select>
<select name="type" id="type2" onchange="mostrarDatos()" >
    <option value="1">Circle</option>
    <option value="2">Cross</option>
    <option value="3">Diamond</option>
    <option value="4">Square</option>
    <option value="5">Star</option>
    <option value="6">Triangle</option>
    <option value="7">Wye</option>
</select>
```

Esta es la parte del código que define los símbolos y las posiciones de los datos.

```
function getSymbol(i)
{
    console.log($( "#type" ).val())
    var valor = $( "#type" ).val()

    if($("#eae").prop('checked') == true)               
    {
        valor = $( "#type" ).val()                          
    }                               
    if($("#arab").prop('checked') == true)
    {
        valor=$( "#type2" ).val()
    }
    switch(valor) {
        case "1":
            //return d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolCircle)
            return d3.symbolCircle
            break;
        case "2":
            //return d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolCross)
            return d3.symbolCross
            break;
        case "3":
            //return d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolDiamond)
            return d3.symbolDiamond
            break;
        case "4":
            //return d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolSquare)
            return d3.symbolSquare
            break;
        case "5":
            //return d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolStar)
            return d3.symbolStar
            break;
        case "6":
            //return d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolTriangle)
            return d3.symbolTriangle
            break;
        case "7":
            //return d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolWye)
            return d3.symbolWye
            break;
        default:
            //return d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolCircle)
            return d3.symbolCircle
    }
}
function mostrarDatos()
{
    nowData=[]
    $(".puntos").remove()
    if($("#eae").prop('checked') == true)
    {
        nowData.push(eaepunt1[coundata])
        simbolo1 = getSymbol(0);
        //grupoDatos.selectAll("circle")
    }               
    if($("#arab").prop('checked') == true)
    {
        nowData.push(arabpunt1[coundata])
        simbolo2 = getSymbol(0);
    }
    for(i=0;i<nowData.length;i++){
        grupoDatos.append("path")
            .attr("class", "puntos")
            .style("stroke","black")
            //.attr("d",getSymbol())
            .attr(
                "d",
                d3.symbol().size(75).type(getSymbol(i))                             
            )
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + xScale(nowData[i][0]) + "," + yScale(nowData[i][1]) + ")"; })
    }
    $("#eae").change(function()
    {
        mostrarDatos();
    });

    $("#arab").change(function()
    {
        mostrarDatos()
    });
```

Me estaba basando en este [ejemplo](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/76d6fa0dff4af77544da9dd69aef9249) en el que define el símbolo dependiendo del valor que hay dentro de su array. En mi caso es algo distinto, necesito definir el símbolo dependiendo de el `checkbox` seleccionado.

grupoDatos se define de la siguiente manera:
`var grupoDatos = grupopadre.append("svg:g");`

`eaepunt1` y `arabpunt1` son arrays con x e y dentro, estas son sus definiciones:

```
var eaepunt1= [[ 0.0158805449205635, -0.680326018437805], [ 0.0201438176742992, -0.322312871396833],
            [ 0.011640654341047, -0.133062815623676], [ 0.00470902597547251, -0.0785467869785874],
            [ 0.000727198634624893, -0.100827296313506]]

var arabpunt1 = [[ -0.00762487179614224, -0.286532935896321],
            [ -0.00596028103084867, -0.439856557949277], [ 0.00757981604246827, -0.324879938829326],
            [ 0.0109876907050404, -0.143217505450856], [ 0.00633027759899818, -0.0511716852747039],
            [ -0.000185594935602662, -0.0837417695707179]]
```

Comment: Estoy tratando de hacerte un snippet funcional, pero me dice que `eaepunt1` no está definido. Podrías añadir su definición a tu pregunta? (`grupoDatos ` tampoco está definido)

Comment: Perdon se me habia olvidado, mira la edicion.

Comment: Da igual, el error no estaba ahí. Te respondí usando valores imaginarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me inventé los valores que faltaban para hacer un snippet y supuse que `grupoDatos` representa un elemento `svg`. Casi no he usado D3 en mi vida, pero encontré dos problemas que son ajenos al manejo interno de D3.

**Primero**, estás declarando los listeners del evento `change` de tus checkboxes dentro de la función `mostrarDatos`. Eso hace que hasta que un select no cambie, el **checkbox no hace nada**, pero de ahí en adelante, cualquier cambio vuelve a llamar a `mostrarDatos` y por lo tanto vuelve a declarar los listeners, los cuales **se van acumulando**.

```
function mostrarDatos()
{
...
    $("#eae").change(function()
    {
        mostrarDatos();
    });

    $("#arab").change(function()
    {
        mostrarDatos()
    });
}
```

**Solución**: declarar esos listeners afuera de la función.

```
function mostrarDatos()
{
...
}

$("#eae").change(function()
{
    mostrarDatos();
});

$("#arab").change(function()
{
    mostrarDatos()
});
```

---

**Segundo**, en tu función `getSymbol` estás recibiendo como parámetro el orden relativo del checkbox que lo está llamando. Sin embargo, el valor que utilizas para discriminar el símbolo a retornar viene de la condición activo/inactivo de los checkboxes

```
function getSymbol(i)
{
    var valor = $( "#type" ).val()

    if($("#eae").prop('checked') == true)               
    {
        valor = $( "#type" ).val()                          
    }                               
    if($("#arab").prop('checked') == true)
    {
        valor=$( "#type2" ).val()
    }
    switch(valor) {

    }
}
```

Bajo esa lógica, si `#arab` está activo, la función `getSymbol` **siempre** pasa por `valor=$( "#type2" ).val()` **ignorando por completo** el valor del primer selector.

**Solución**: utilizar el parámetro `i` que ya está recibiendo

```
function getSymbol(i)
{
    if(i===1)               
    {
        valor = $( "#type2" ).val()                          
    } else {                              
        valor = $( "#type" ).val()
    }
    switch(valor) {

    }
}
```

**Tercero**: te dejé un snippet con mi solución burda y datos inventados.

```js
function getSymbol(valor)
{
    
    switch(valor) {
        case "1":
            //return d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolCircle)
            return d3.symbolCircle
            break;
        case "2":
            //return d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolCross)
            return d3.symbolCross
            break;
        case "3":
            //return d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolDiamond)
            return d3.symbolDiamond
            break;
        case "4":
            //return d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolSquare)
            return d3.symbolSquare
            break;
        case "5":
            //return d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolStar)
            return d3.symbolStar
            break;
        case "6":
            //return d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolTriangle)
            return d3.symbolTriangle
            break;
        case "7":
            //return d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolWye)
            return d3.symbolWye
            break;
        default:
            //return d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolCircle)
            return d3.symbolCircle
    }
}
function mostrarDatos()
{
    var grupoDatos=d3.select('#grupodatos'),
    nowData=[],
    symbolData=[],
    coundata=0,
    eaepunt1=[[10,10]],
    arabpunt1=[[50,10]];
    $(".puntos").remove()
    if($("#eae").prop('checked') == true)
    {
        nowData.push(eaepunt1[coundata]);
        symbolData.push($( "#type" ).val());
    }               
    if($("#arab").prop('checked') == true)
    {
        nowData.push(arabpunt1[coundata]);
        symbolData.push($( "#type2" ).val());
    }
     for(i=0;i<nowData.length;i++){
         grupoDatos.append("path")
            .attr("class", "puntos")
            .style("stroke","black")
            //.attr("d",getSymbol())
            .attr(
                "d",
                d3.symbol().size(75).type(getSymbol(symbolData[i]))                             
            )
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate("+nowData[i][0]+","+nowData[i][1]+")"; })
    }
    

    

}

     $("#eae").change(function()
    {
         mostrarDatos();
    });

    $("#arab").change(function()
    {
         mostrarDatos()
    });
```

```css
#grupodatos {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.7.3/d3.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="planned_checked"  id="eae" > eaepunt1
<input type="checkbox" name="planned_checked"  id="arab" > arabpunt1
<br>

<select name="type" id="type" onchange="mostrarDatos()" >
    <option value="1">Circle</option>
    <option value="2">Cross</option>
    <option value="3">Diamond</option>
    <option value="4">Square</option>
    <option value="5">Star</option>
    <option value="6">Triangle</option>
    <option value="7">Wye</option>
</select>
<select name="type" id="type2" onchange="mostrarDatos()" >
    <option value="1">Circle</option>
    <option value="2">Cross</option>
    <option value="3">Diamond</option>
    <option value="4">Square</option>
    <option value="5">Star</option>
    <option value="6">Triangle</option>
    <option value="7">Wye</option>
</select>

<svg id="grupodatos"></svg>
```

Nota al margen, este d3 v4 se ve igual a la v3 a grandes rasgos.

**EDIT**: había un error en el código, porque estaba asumiendo que las posiciones de los elementos dentro de los array auxiliares eran fijas, cuando en realidad se utiliza `[].push` y, por tanto, un checkbox puede estar en cualquier posición (según la configuración de encendidos y apagados)

Comment: Hay un problema en el codigo, si seleciono los dos check, y les doy un simbolo distinto a cada uno, funciona bien, pero en el momento que deseleciono el primer check el simbolo del segundo se cambia. Habia conseguido una solucion parecida pero me pasaba lo mismo, que el segundo check cogia el selector del primero

Comment: Tienes razón. Estaba haciendo un supuesto erróneo. Por favor revísalo ahora.